# Heroku deployment for Ruby / Sinatra / Postgres app "PG::ConnectionBad"

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, rake

I’ve deployed my Ruby app on Heroku, however when looking to register or login I’m having an internal server error. My app is built on Sinatra and Rake.

When doing `heroku logs -tail` I’m having the following error message:

```
PG::ConnectionBad - connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

I installed the heroku Postgres add-on. I migrated my db with the following command:
`heroku pg:push makersbnb DATABASE --app makersbnb-challenge`

Here is one of my lib file with my PG connections:

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User

    attr_reader :user_id, :username

    def initialize(user_id:, username:)
        @user_id = user_id
        @username = username
    end

    def self.register(username:, password: )
        if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'test' 
            connection = PG.connect(dbname: "makersbnb_test")
        else
            connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'makersbnb')
        end

        encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)

        result = connection.exec_params("INSERT INTO users (username, password)
        VALUES ($1, $2)
        RETURNING user_id, username, password;",[username, encrypted_password])

        User.new(user_id: result[0]['user_id'], username: result[0]['username'])
    end

    def self.authenticate(username:, password:)
        if ENV['ENVIRONMENT'] == 'test' 
            connection = PG.connect(dbname: "makersbnb_test")
        else
            connection = PG.connect(dbname: 'makersbnb')
        end

        result = connection.query(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1",
            [username]
          )
        return unless result.any?
        return unless BCrypt::Password.new(result[0]['password']) == password
        User.new(user_id: result[0]['user_id'], username: result[0]['username'])
    end
end
```

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
ruby '3.1.0'
gem "sinatra"
gem "sinatra-contrib"
gem "rake"
gem 'pg'
gem 'webrick'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'rack-flash3'
gem "sinatra-activerecord"    # for Active Record models

gem 'capybara', group: :test
gem 'rspec', group: :test
```

I also created a database.yml file based on other instructions I read but I'm not sure if it applies in this case:

```
# database.yml file
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 pool: 5
test:
 <<: *default
 database: makersbnb_test
production:
 <<: *default
 database: makersbnb
```

Here is the [repo](https://github.com/lauracabtay/airbnb_challenge)
Here is the [app](https://makersbnb-challenge.herokuapp.com/)
Help!

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain the problem, but also point some other flaws of Your current approach
To connect to remote database You should specify some options in

```rb
connection = PG.connect(dbname: "makersbnb")
```

You should specify not only dbname option but also:

- host
- user
- password
  Those can be retrieved from heroku postgresql config

```rb
connection = PG.connect(dbname: "makersbnb", host: <db_host>, user: <db_user>, password: <db_password>)
```

**REMEMBER DON'T SET THOSE VALUES IN YOUR CODE**
Instead You can use env variables.

- Your config file is not doing anything in this approach
- In the script You also don't use ActiveRecord. To do so Your model class should inherit from ActiveRecord::Base, something like this:

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here You can find some information how to use ActiveRecord without Rails framework: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/ruby-activerecord-without-rails-tutorial
And also some more information how to use it in sinatra specifically:
https://github.com/sinatra-activerecord/sinatra-activerecord